# Angular ngFor with dynamic adding of objects

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular8, angular-arrays

Please check the video: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqQQj2tA22

I'm adding dynamically objects to an array and would like to set the values once the objects are added. Now when I'm adding a new object to the array all the input textboxes in the loop are resetting the value shown in the textbox although the array is keeping the correct properties in the code.

This is my markup:

```html
<div *ngFor="let colorSet of quantity.colorSets; let k=index;">
    <div>
        <label>Color Sets:</label>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.colorSets[k].setQ" value="{{quantity.colorSets[k].setQ}}" name="colorSetQ-{{index}}" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Price:</label>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.colorSets[k].price" value="{{colorSet.price}}" name="colorSetPrice-{{index}}" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the code:

```js
model: any = {
    TenantId: '',
    CustomFieldName: '',
    quantities: []
};

newQuantity = {
    price: '',
    rangestart: '',
    rangeend: '',
    colorSets: []
};

colorSetInfo = {
    setQ: '',
    price: ''
}

addNewPriceSet(quantitySet) {
    if (quantitySet) {
        quantitySet.colorSets.push({
            setQ: '',
            price: ''
        });
        console.log(quantitySet);
        console.log(this.model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: Can you try to change `name="colorSetQ-{{index}}"` to `name="colorSetQ-{{k}}"`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner that was it! Tesekurler

Comment: @Laziale I've posted it as an answer. Can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. You don't have `index` in your scope (within `ngFor`).

Change `name="colorSetQ-{{index}}"` to `name="colorSetQ-{{k}}"`

And

`name="colorSetPrice-{{index}}"` to `name="colorSetPrice-{{k}}"`

Comment: There is no need to answer typo questions - there is a specific close reason just for that category.